# Extract a variable from a action performer(combobox) and use it in a query

Tags: java, mysql, variables, combobox

Here is the public global variable:

```
 public static String s;
```

Here is the  SQL query -> normaly its working but without the condition WHERE

```
 String query = "SELECT * FROM `asistente` WHERE `sectie`="+s;
            System.out.println(s);
            Statement st;
            ResultSet rs;
```

> s-> equal NULL

Populate the ComboBox  -> its working

```
public void fillComboBox() {

        try {
            String a = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/licenta";
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(a, "root", "");
            String query = "SELECT * FROM `sectii`";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                comboBoxSectie.addItem(rs.getString("sectie"));
                comboBoxFilterSectie.addItem(rs.getString("sectie"));

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here im trying to give to s the value from the combobox

```
  public ModificareDB() {

comboBoxFilterSectie = new JComboBox();
        comboBoxFilterSectie.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            s=(String) comboBoxFilterSectie.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println(s);
            }
        });
```

> -> s is equal with value selected

How can I use the value selected from comboBox in the query?